# EF core 'Unknown column in feld list' after adding property in partial class

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core

I have a DB-first EF core model `OrderableItem` with a helper property added in its partial part:

```
public partial class OrderableItem {

  public decimal EffectivePrice {
    get => IsSpecial ? Special.Price : Price;
    set {
      if (IsSpecial)
        Special.Price = value;
      else 
        Price = value;
    }
  }
}
```

however, after adding this property I can no longer query the DbSet (MySql provider), throwing an exception:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unknown column 'i.EffectivePrice' in 'field list'
```

while the exception is clear, it does not make any sence why EF is trying to query a property that is not defined in model (and should not be!). How can I fix this issue? Am I limited to methods in partials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, EF Core would try to map all the properties as long as they have both getter and setter. If you need to ignore a specific property, you can use [`NotMapped` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute?view=netcore-3.1):

```
public partial class OrderableItem {

  [NotMapped]
  public decimal EffectivePrice {
    get => IsSpecial ? Special.Price : Price;
    set {
      if (IsSpecial)
        Special.Price = value;
      else 
        Price = value;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, that is a counter intuitive default setting for db-first models.

Answer (score 2):

You should specify properties which should be ignored by DbContext using modelBuilder's method ignore. `builder.Entity<OrderableItem>().Ignore(x => x.EffectivePrice)`. 
You can achieve same using attributes but if your class is used as domain entity then it should not contain any infrastructure dependencies.